# CPU usage monitoring in AIX servers

Tags: performance, monitoring, aix

In order to monitor the CPU usage in an AIX server I'm using the following script that is executed every 10 mins.

```
lparstat 2 10 > cpu
usage=$(tail -10 cpu | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0;} {sum+=$4} END{print int(100-sum/10)}')


if [[ $usage -ge 90 ]]; then
# mail the error and cpu file to admin
# displaying this for testing purposes
echo "CPU usage off the charts!!!"
cat cpu
fi
```

However, in case the CPU usage is above 90% I need to list the top 5 Processes that are using the CPU.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can list the top 5 in a fairly readable way by limiting the columns, sorting them with the highest CPU usage first, and then truncating to the first 5 (using `head -6`, since we also want to include the headers):

```
ps -eo pcpu,pid,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -6
```

The output looks something like this:

```
%CPU   PID COMMAND
 2.0 30531 -bash
 0.0 30673 head -6
 0.0 30672 sort -k 1 -r
 0.0 30671 ps -eo pcpu,pid,args
 0.0 30670 [flush-253:0]
```

You might also want to look into GNU `top`'s batch mode (`-b`).

Comment: Unfortunately in the AIX system that I'm uing `top` is unavailable and has `topas`. 
`ps -eo pcpu,pid,args | sort -rk1 | head -6` does give the output, but the result doesn't match with the result of `topas`.

Comment: @debal Why must the result match `topas`?

Comment: both these commands tend to do the same thing, wouldn't it be surprising if the two results don't match? `topas` is giving a realtime view of the CPU usage, `ps -eo pcpu,pid,args | sort -rk1 | head -6` is giving for a particular point of time, so at that instance it only makes sense if both these commands provide the same result. Which is not the case.

Comment: That's not exactly the contrast point -- ps gives you a weird process lifetime vs. CPU seconds which is not necessarily indicative of what's causing high CPU "recently".

topas, like top, gives you the % over a much short reasonable that is intuitively usually what people want.

Answer (score 0):

For a deep dive, the best course of action here is to run

`tprof -skex sleep 10`

which will give you a report detailing the processes using high CPU, then drill down into usage by function and shared libraries.

Answer (score -1):

you can use below command it will match with topas output

```
ps -ef | egrep -v "STIME|$LOGNAME" | sort +3 -r | head -n 15
```